# Diffenrence between NLS_UPPER and UPPER

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am new in PL/SQL Language. I saw there were 2 functions in `PL/SQL`: `UPPER` and `NLS_UPPER`. They both do the same thing. I want to know the difference between of these functions. thanks

Comment: Refer this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch9sql.htm
or this http://psoug.org/definition/NLS_UPPER.htm for NLS_UPPER spec

Comment: Please, I'm just curious, why downvote?

Comment: I didn't see any reason either for a downvote. So I've given you an upvote and you are back to zero. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NLS_UPPER` knows about locale specific rules

This query:

```
select nls_upper('ß', 'NLS_SORT = XGerman') as upper1, 
       upper('ß') as upper2
from dual;
```

returns the following:

```
UPPER1 | UPPER2
-------+-------
SS     | ß
```

see the difference?